# Remove part of a string from List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have a `List<string>`, the string part representing filenames that I need to filter out: anything that comes before the character '&' included must be erased.

```
List<string> zippedTransactions = new List<string>();
zippedTransactions.Add("33396&20151007112154000549659S03333396SUMMARIES.PDF");
zippedTransactions.Add("33395&20151007112400000549659S03333395SUMMARIES.PDF");
zippedTransactions.Add("33397&20151007112555000549659S03333397SUMMARIES.PDF");

// desired output:
// "20151007112154000549659S03333396SUMMARIES.PDF";
// "20151007112400000549659S03333395SUMMARIES.PDF";
// "20151007112555000549659S03333397SUMMARIES.PDF"
```

**NOTE**: I don't want to give it the classic iterative-style look, since C# provides for plentiful of functional interfaces to interact with this sort of data structure, I want to start using it.

Comment: Okay, so have you tried anything yet? I would suggest tackling this in two steps: 1) work out how to obtain the desired value for a *single* input string. 2) Work out how to apply that to a list of strings.

Comment: I have an approach of using foreach, but I want to avoid iteration of loop.

Comment: Well *something* is going to have to iterate, isn't it? You could use LINQ to move the iteration into library code, but it's still going to involve iteration.

Comment: So _why_ exactly do you want to overcomplicate something that's just a simple for-loop...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one Linq approach with RegEx

```
Transactions = Transactions.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, ".*&", string.Empty)).ToList();
```

That's more fault tolerant compared to `Split('&')[1]` in case there is no `&` in your filename

Comment: Awesome but it's still going to involve iteration internally.

Answer (score 0):

following code will help you

```
for (int i = 0; i < zippedTransactions.Count; i++)
{
    string[] result = zippedTransactions[i].Split('&');
    zippedTransactions[i] = result[result.Length-1];
}
```

Comment: Not quite right. This would not only need a length check on `result` , but will also not act right if there are multiple & characters in the string; only the last piece is required. Since String.Split always gives at least one result in the array, a better solution would be `zippedTransactions[i] = result[result.Length-1];`

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Split to split the string at the desired character and retrieve the portion that you want:

```
foreach (var item in zippedTransactions)
{
    string[] result = item.Split('&');
    Console.WriteLine(result[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < zippedTransactions.Count; i++)
                {
                   zippedTransactions[i] = zippedTransactions[i].Split('&')[1]; 
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string.IndexOf function to find the location of a character in the string and then use string.Remove to remove the characters up to that point:

```
for(int i =0; i < zippedTransactions.Count; i++)
{
    int count = zippedTransactions[i].IndexOf("&") + 1;
    zippedTransactions[i] = zippedTransactions[i].Remove(0, count);
}
```

Comment: It's good to add some words to describe your answer rather than posting a code only answer

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have visual studio, and a version that supports [C# Interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough), I suggest you try this.

```
> zippedTransactions = new List<string>() { 
    "33396&20151007112154000549659S03333396SUMMARIES.PDF", 
    "33395&20151007112400000549659S03333395SUMMARIES.PDF", 
    "33397&20151007112555000549659S03333397SUMMARIES.PDF"
  };
> 
> zippedTransactions.Select(dirname => dirname.Split('&')[1])
Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<string, string> { "20151007112154000549659S03333396SUMMARIES.PDF", "20151007112400000549659S03333395SUMMARIES.PDF", "20151007112555000549659S03333397SUMMARIES.PDF" }
>
```

And even if you don't, you can get an idea of what's happening just by looking at the code.

The `WhereSelectListIterator` is a data structure holding the logic you intend to execute on the data structure. It is evaluated (read: the loop actually happens) only when you consume it (for example, calling `.ToList()` at the end).

This code will only take the second element coming after splitting the string on '&', so you might wanna generalize it or tune it for your requirements.